# Capsule Collider not visible in the scene view?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to hit a ball using a golf club. My golf club has three components (three game objects: handle, shaft and head as shown in the first attached image). Head gameobject's inspector can be seen in the another attached image.
To hit the golf ball, we need a collider. So I put a Capsule Collider at head game object. But I don't see any collider at head gameobject.
The head is shown in the last image.
Why I can't put Capsule Collider at the object?

[image: gameobjects.png]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Thanks for the reply.

I increased the radius but still the same.

I placed a Quad in the scene and put Mesh collider onto it (called AW52Collider). Please see in the
first image. We can see the collider clearly.

But I did the same thing to Club head, as it is also a game object I should be able to put a Mesh collider. But I don't see anything. Why?

Please see in the second image.

One more thing I don't understand is when I put AW52Collider inside Club Head object, I don't see AW52Collider also. Why? Please see in the third image.

[image]
[image] 
[image]

Comment: That radius looks a bit small. Have you tried increasing the radius as well as the height of the collider?

Comment: @Tom thanks, I made bigger radius but still the same. I did a few testing and added EDIT in the original post. Can please explain if you have any idea? Since I am new to Unity I can't figure immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Increase the size of your collider, those values do not look like you should see the gizmos at all. Best would be to reset the collider to its default values and then play with them until you are happy.
2. It is best practice to create a child object with colliders on it. The reason is the placement of the collider. The collider is always centered around the pivot point of a `GameObject`. But you probably want to move your collider freely or disable a group of colliders manually for testing (or optimization) purposes. Also consider that an object with multiple small colliders as child objects is considered one big collider (rigidbody wise). [Source (Compound Colliders)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)

Comment: Yes I increased the size but still can't see. I added a quad, then put Mesh collider onto the quad.  is that what you mean?  Is that a correct way? I did some testing and added EDIT at the bottom of the original post. Could explain me since I am new to Unity. Thanks

Comment: Just add a GameObject and add the collider to it. Did you check "generate colliders" while importing your mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Just enable Gizmos button and you'll find your capsule collider.

See this picture to know exactly where to find it:

[image]

(It's in the toolbar below the Scene tab)